# Construct biggest stacked tower with blocs and restriction

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Problem**

The problem is to build the tallest tower made up of cylinders, respecting all the rules.

- Will be arranged on the table, an amount of N cylinders.
- Each cylinder has one color: Red, orange, green or blue.
- Each cylinder has one heigth h and a base with radius of size r.
- To the build the tower, the cylinders should to be stacked, and the
  top cylinder should ever have the base smaller that the base of the
  cylinder below it. Except the first cylinder, it can have the base of
  any size, since there is no other cylinder below it.

There are also some restrictions very interesting on colors of the cylinders. They are described below.

- A red cylinder cannot to be put on an orange cylinder
- An orange cylinder cannot to be put on a blue cylinder
- A blue cylinder cannot to be put on a green cylinder
- A green cylinder cannot to be put on a red cylinder

**Input**

> The input contains several test cases. The first line of each test case contains an integer N (1 <= N <= 10^3), representing the number of cylinders arranged on the table, following N rows, each row having a height h (1 <= h <= 1000) of the cylinder in centimeters, the radius r (1 <= r <= 1000) of the cylinder base and a word p, representing the color of the cylinder. The word can be: RED, ORANGE, GREEN, or BLUE. The end of input is indicated as N = 0, which should not be processed.

**Output**

> For each test case, your program should print a single line with the value the height of the largest cylinders tower that can be built, followed by the word "centimeter(s)”.

**Sample Input**

> ```
> 5   
> 5 3 RED    
> 4 2 ORANGE   
> 1 1 GREEN    
> 3 5 ORANGE    
> 2 4 BLUE    
> 3    
> 10 10 ORANGE    
> 5 10 GREEN    
> 6 5 RED    
> 0
> ```

**Sample Output**

> ```
> 15 centimeter(s)    
> 11 centimeter(s)
> ```

I've tried to solve this problem with dynamic programming, but it takes more than 8 secs to give a answer with a big input (inside the limits); Is this solution right for this problem ? Is there another algorithm ?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000

#define NON -1
#define RED 3
#define ORA 2
#define BLU 1
#define GRE 0

struct cylinder_t{
    int h,r,c;
    cylinder_t():h(0),r(0),c(0){}
    cylinder_t(int height, int radius, int color):h(height),r(radius),c(color){}
};

inline bool compare (const cylinder_t &i,const cylinder_t &j) {
    return i.r > j.r;
}

cylinder_t cylinder[MAX];
inline bool canPut(int i, int last_cylinder_onStack){

    if(last_cylinder_onStack == NON)
        return true;

    if (cylinder[i].r >= cylinder[last_cylinder_onStack].r)
        return false;

    if((cylinder[i].c - cylinder[last_cylinder_onStack].c + 4)%4 == 1)
        return false;

    return true;
}

int memo[MAX][MAX];
int dp(int tower_size, int size, int last_cylinder_onStack){
    if(tower_size == size)
        return 0;

    if(last_cylinder_onStack != NON && memo[tower_size][last_cylinder_onStack] != -1)
        return memo[tower_size][last_cylinder_onStack];

    int maxHeight = 0;
    for (int c = tower_size; c < size; ++c) {
        if(canPut(c, last_cylinder_onStack))
            maxHeight = std::max(maxHeight, cylinder[c].h + dp(tower_size + 1, size, c));
    }

    if(last_cylinder_onStack == NON)
        return maxHeight;
    return memo[tower_size][last_cylinder_onStack] = maxHeight;
}

int main(void){
    //clock_t t;
    //t = clock();

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
    map["RED"]    = RED;
    map["ORANGE"] = ORA;
    map["GREEN"]  = GRE;
    map["BLUE"]   = BLU;

    int n;
    while(scanf("%d",&n), n != 0){

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int height,radius;
            char color[15];
            scanf("%d %d %s",&height,&radius,&color[0]);
            cylinder[i].h = height;
            cylinder[i].r = radius;
            cylinder[i].c = map[std::string(color)];
        }

        std::sort(cylinder, cylinder + n, compare);

        memset(memo, -1, sizeof(memo));
        printf("%d centimeter(s)\n",dp(0,n, NON));
    }

    //t = clock() - t;
    //printf("Took %lf seconds to execute \n",((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

I've made a INPUT generator in JAVA for this problem:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Random r = new Random();
        String color[] = {"RED","ORANGE","GREEN","BLUE"};

        int t = 20;//number of test cases
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int n = r.nextInt(1000) + 1; //number of cylinders
            System.out.println(n);
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d %d %s\n",r.nextInt(1000) + 1,r.nextInt(1000) + 1,color[r.nextInt(4)]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("0");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your idea looks correct, but you could get rid of the recursion and compute a `dp` array like you would for the longest increasing subsequence problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite strange that your dp table has both `tower_size` and `last_cylinder_on_stack` parameters. I think that dp should depend only on `last_cylinder_on_stack`. In the recursion function, you know the last cylinder on stack, so you clearly should loop only from `last_cylinder_on_stack+1`

So I think that you should get rid of `last_cylinder_onStack` parameter and have the main loop as

```
for (int c = last_cylinder_onStack+1; c < size; ++c) {
    if(canPut(c, last_cylinder_onStack))
        maxHeight = std::max(maxHeight, cylinder[c].h + dp(size, c));
}
```

Comment: also you come from Russia

Comment: @kaitian, Petr (Петр) is a very common Russian given name, having the same roots as English Peter